# ThreadPoolExecutor : Tasks are getting queued up and not submitted

Tags: java, threadpoolexecutor

We have a scenario where tasks submitted to ThreadPoolExecutor are long running. When the thread pool is started we start it with core pool size = 5, max pool size = 20 and queue size of 10. In our application around 10 tasks get submitted. Most of the time these tasks run for few mins/hrs and then complete. However there was a situation when all of the 5 tasks got hanged on I/O. As a result my core pool size reached it max, but my Threadpoolexecutor queue was not full. So the additional 5 tasks never got a chance to run.
Please do suggest how we can handle such scenario? Is having a smaller queue better option in such situation? What would be an optimum queue size while initializing threadPool?

Also regarding the hanged tasks, is there any way we can pull out the threads out of the Threadpool? In that case at least other tasks would get a chance to run.

Comment: When you submit() a task, you are returned a Future object.  You can use that future object to cancel execution.

Comment: Yes we are doing that using future.cancel. However it is not guaranteed that tasks would get cancelled esp when waiting on I/O.

Comment: you can set the timeout value while getting value using Future object as `future.get(5000,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)` and write this within `try catch` block.

Answer (score 15):

The overall situation is like this:

```
core pool size = 5,
max pool size = 20 and 
queue size of 10
```

10 tasks are submitted. Out of which

1. 5 Tasks hanged on I/O => all threads of core pool size are occupied. And hence there is no idle thread.
2. 5 Tasks are remained . These 5 threads are enqueued to queue since there is no idle thread and the queue can accommodate 10 tasks. These enqueued tasks will not execute until either the queue is full or any of the threads in core pool is free.

Hence, Your Program is hanged .

To know more about dynamics of `ThreadPoolExecutor` watch [**here**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) . The notable points of this doc is as follows:

- If fewer than corePoolSize threads are running, the Executor always prefers adding a new thread rather than queuing.
- If corePoolSize or more threads are running, the Executor always prefers queuing a request rather than adding a new thread.
- If a request cannot be queued, a new thread is created unless this would exceed maximumPoolSize, in which case, the task will be rejected.

**EDIT**
If you wish to increase core pool size then you can use **[setCorePoolSize(int corePoolSize)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#setCorePoolSize%28int%29)** . If you increase the `corepoolsize` then new threads will, if needed, be started to execute any queued tasks.

Comment: Sure, you can increase the corePoolSize, but still will face the possibility that all tasks hang and block the Executor's threads

Answer (score 10):

The [Javadocs for ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) states:

Any BlockingQueue may be used to transfer and hold submitted tasks. The use of this queue interacts with pool sizing:

- If fewer than corePoolSize threads are running, the Executor always
  prefers adding a new thread rather than queuing.
- If corePoolSize or
  more threads are running, the Executor always prefers queuing a
  request rather than adding a new thread.
- If a request cannot be
  queued, a new thread is created unless this would exceed
  maximumPoolSize, in which case, the task will be rejected.

Unless you exceed your queue size after 5 threads are "hanging", you're not going to get more threads.

The real answer is: fix the problem that's causing your threads to hang. Otherwise you're going to have to implement some scheme that uses the `Future`s returned by `submit()` to cancel threads if they are running too long.

Comment: I agree. We are trying to avoid hanging of threads as much as possible. But in production scenario, there is still a very low chance that threads hang as its waiting on some other system/app. In that case, the scenario which I observed would completely stop my whole application.

Comment: Correct. Which is why *you need to fix that problem*. There is *no reason* to have code that allows them to "hang" in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

I think another approach would be to set the corePoolSize based on the the number of tasks waiting in the queue. One can control the corePoolSize by using setCorePoolSize. A sample monitor thread can control you threadPoolExecutor. You can also improve this monitor to adjust the degree of parallelism.

```
    public class ExecutorMonitor extends Thread{

            ThreadPoolExecutor executor = null;
            int initialCorePoolSize;
            public ExecutorMonitor(ThreadPoolExecutor executor)
            {
                this.executor = executor;
                this.initialCorePoolSize = executor.getCorePoolSize();
            }
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                while (true)
                {   
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if (executor.getQueue().size() > 0)
                    {
                        if(executor.getActiveCount() < executor.getMaximumPoolSize())
                            executor.setCorePoolSize(executor.getCorePoolSize() + 1);
                    }
                    if (executor.getQueue().size() == 0)
                    {
                        if(executor.getCorePoolSize() > initialCorePoolSize)
                            executor.setCorePoolSize(executor.getCorePoolSize() -1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Does dynamically increasing corePoolSize will create new thread and assign queued task to this new thread?

Comment: @Nishat Yes according do java doc: [setCorePoolSize(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#setCorePoolSize(int))

Answer (score 0):

The "variable" sized thread pool feature in the jdk is a bit tricky.  Basically, the setup you are using won't work very well for the reasons you outlined.  When i want a variable size thread pool, i typically use this setup:

```
   ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(maxPoolSize, maxPoolSize,
                                                         DEFAULT_THREAD_TIMEOUT, DEFAULT_THREAD_TIMEOUT_UNIT,
                                                         new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(),
                                                         threadFactory);
    executor.allowCoreThreadTimeOut(true);
```

this will create a variable sized thread pool which will vary between 1 and maxPoolSize threads.  since the core size is the same as the max size, the pool will always prefer adding threads to queuing, thus you will never backup your queue until the number of threads is maxed out.

UPDATE:
As for your hanging tasks problem, if there is an upper limit on the length of a task, you could have a separate manager track the outstanding Future's and cancel them if they are over the max running time.  this, of course, assumes your tasks are interruptible.

Comment: Worth noting is that without fixing his actual problem ... this is going to keep creating threads until it hits max (or he gets an OOM error before that, of course). It's more a bandaid than a solution.

Comment: @BrianRoach - how is this a bandaid solution?

Comment: Because exactly of what I just said in my comment? In a long running process he will run out of threads or memory because he has tasks that are hanging. Fixing the real problem (his threads hanging on I/O) eliminates any need to change his current setup. The whole point of using an executor instead of just spawning threads is to control the number of threads (and manage them).

Comment: @BrianRoach - ah, you're saying it is a bandaid for the OP because the hanging processes is the real problem.  got it, couldn't agree more!

Comment: `executor.allowCoreThreadTimeOut(true);` will never work unless the entire pool has no tasks at all (totally idle) and then all threads will go bust. The inherent problem is caused by the queue strategy in `LinkedBlockingQueue` as the threads will queue on tasks (more like on the Lock/Condition) and be considered live as long as there is at least one task in DEFAULT_THREAD_TIMEOUT period.

Comment: @bestsss - i don't know where you are getting that from (nor do i completely understand what you are saying).  looking at the logic for ThreadPoolExecutor, if allowCoreThreadTimeout doesn't work (as you assert), then it looks like _none_ of the idle thread logic would work, which would make the TPE impl pretty lousy.  (it's the same logic which handles extra threads as handles the core thread timeout).

Comment: @jtahlborn, *it's the same logic which handles extra threads as handles the core thread timeout* core threads won't timeout unless asked by `allowCoreThreadTimeOut`. But yeah the entire logic is lousy. I did try to solve the issue by having the threads waiting on the condition stack(!) ordered. It does work but pretty much requires writing your queue along with AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.

Comment: @bestsss - i still don't follow where in the current impl you see the problem?

Comment: look at getTask() in j.u.c.TPE, even in non-fair impl. the threads are contending for a task in more or less queued manner (-the possible barge). Each thread must not see a task for the timeout period to be considered timeouted. Now lets say there is no single task for the timeout period (+some extra time from the last execution, but the executions should be relatively 'fast'), all threads will timeout as they are all core ones with allowed expiration.

Comment: @bestsss - from what i can see in TPE.getTask(), the threads ultimately end up in LBQ.poll(timeout).  it sounds like you are saying that if a single task arrives, all the threads will somehow wake up?  i don't really see how.  it looks like only one thread would wake from poll and the rest would eventually return null and get dropped.

Comment: I am not saying that. Imagine you have timeout=10sec and corePoolSize=10, and each second a new task is submitted, the execution takes 2-3ms. Even though actually the ThreadPool is effectively idling, no thread will exit in such a scenario. Now for 10seconds there is no single task submitted and all the threads do exit.

Comment: @bestsss - okay, i think i follow now.  you are saying that the distribution of tasks will be such that even though 1 thread could in theory handle all those tasks, instead a different thread will be awoken for each one, keeping them each from idling out.  in order to spin down well, you want a bias when handing out tasks so that busy threads stay busy and idle threads can timeout.

Comment: yes, pretty much that. On top of it, it's a different thread each time which doesn't help with keeping the caches hot (more in theory, if the underlying queue can busy spin for awhile). If you use stack priority for BlockQueue.poll() only the latest thread attempting poll() stays alive and the rest exit.

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental problem is that the user is really getting CORE_POOL_SIZE threads with unlimited Queue scenario. As such if there are 5 threads in core pool that's all he can ever use, max size does nothing to help. While reducing the time of thread execution is advisable in all cases, in production scenario we cannot often control how third party services will behave and as such the solution would be to increase core pool size to be equal to max pool size or limit the queue size.

Answer (score -4):

i guess the best solution would be override the execute method of ThreadPoolExecutor and introduce the changes in that.