# Scalable priority ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Looking for a solution to optimise processing of workloads, which are coming either from background or from API task sources. Task code is just the single Callable class. I guess that having two separate thread pools for different task sources is less elegant solution. So i need the following properties that ExecutorService should have

- dynamically dynamically adjust task execution order based on Comparable interface. `java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue` does that already. I can pass it as argument to `java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor`, so that's already handled.
- number of threads is preferred to [scale up and down dynamically](http://groovy-programming.com/post/26923146865) (c)

As long as Java community is dynamic, maybe somebody did already solve this problem into any available library? Or should I override PriorityBlockingQueue methods?

Comment: You can get a limited form of auto-scaling using [this pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15032613/552759).  Also, do you care about starvation of lower priority tasks, cause that makes things "more complicated".

Comment: @jtahlborn thanks, any comments are welcome

Comment: @nefo_x What do your jobs (Callables) look like? Are they I/O heavy or just cpu bound? If they are cpu bound, you can only scale up to the number of cores anyway.

Comment: @R4J they have disk only IO

Answer (score 1):

For the dynamically scaling part, this may help a bit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19538899/999043 (actually, you want to read the other answers, too). 
For the priority part, make sure sorting the queue and inserting does not impact scalability.